# Is renaming a project supposed to be this hard?

Tags: java, android, xml, package, rename

I started this project a long long time ago when I was just beginning at programming. It was based off of one of the android open source examples but by now it has very very little of the original code in it. Rather than starting a new project from scratch and copying and pasting I thought I could just rename this one.

Boy is it giving me some problems.

First of all, I did successfully change the name of the app, that's easy enough... just change the string. The problem is actually trying to change the package name.

To do it I clicked on the package under the src folder and hit F2, and renamed the package.
I verified and the package name in all of the files did update except for a few places in the manifest. But i'm getting all sorts of errors no matter what I do.

I noticed for one that even though the package name is changed, under the gen folder, the old package name still generates containing the R file. Not sure why.

Also noticed I have 2 res folders. One at the top hierarchy in the tree and one under the bin folder which is empty.

And yes I've tried a clean/rebuild and ctrl+shft+o a million times.

Any thoughts?

Comment: is the activity name in your manifest matching what you have?

Comment: @ aleph: I did discover that this was also a problem, the activity was declared in the manifest using the <full.package.name>.Activity convention vs just ".Activity" and the package name wasn't updating. Fixed this, but it wasn't the only problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right Click your project -> Android Tools -> Rename Application Package.

Comment: Wow who knew? lol that was simple enough. I guess this must mean i was just missing some places I was supposed to change the name, and this tool is better at it than me.

Comment: I went through what you did a couple of months ago. This tool is better at it than most people lol.